# How to make WP_Query array (category_name) updateable from admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I need to make a section in wordpress admin panel (page editor), so admin can physically choose (or write) a category. And then created page (custom template) shows only selected (written) category posts.

Normally I would specify that in code like so:

```
    <?php $works = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'category_name' => 'My Category Name'
    )); ?>
```

Now I need to achive something like that:

```
    <?php $works = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'category_name' => 'THIS TEXT IS EDITABLE IN A CUSTOM FIELD FROM ADMIN PANEL'
    )); ?>
```

Currently I have tried this code, but it does not work like I expected:

```
    <?php $works = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'category_name' => '<?php $categoryname = types_render_field("category-name", array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";")); echo $categoryname; ?>'
    )); ?>
```

PS. I am not a hardcore php/wordpress developer - still learning.

Any help and suggestions? Maybe I am missing something really stupid and simple here?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create the meta box.

You need to create a meta box so that you can display and save the form field. You do that with the WordPress function `add_meta_box()`. Wrap that in a function and hook it to `add_meta_boxes`

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

**Step 2:** Display the form field

The third param of `add_meta_box()` allows you to specify a callback function which prints out your form field in the meta box.

Perhaps something like `<input type="text" name="category_name" value="" />`

**Step 3:** Check if a value has been given and use that in your `WP_Query`

Based on your code above, that would be something like this:

```
$works = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'category_name' => $_POST['category_name'] )
));
```

**Note:** It's also good practice to use a WordPress nonce to verify the request came from the right screen and with proper authorisation.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces